# How to make use of the rest of the height in a HTML layout

Tags: html, css, height

My question is simple, I have three `div`s in my layout:

```
<div id="header">90px height</div>
<div id="content">the rest of the height of the window</div>
<div id="footer">20px height</div>
```

Now, I want the `#content` `div` to fill the rest of the window. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.................***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/5PN3zWmT)***.....................

Hi now you can used to `position` `absolute` and `fixed`

**as like this**

**Css**

```
#header{
height:90px;
  background:red;
}

#content{
background:yellow;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:90px;
  bottom:20px;
}

#footer{
height:20px;
  background:green;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

**[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/5PN3zWmT)**

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery to find the window height

```
var h = $(window).height();
$("#content").css("height", h);
```

if you want width

```
var w = $(window).width();
$("#content").css("width", w);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var height = $(window).height() - $("#header").height() - $("#footer").height();

$("#content").height(height + "px");
```